# Commutation relations in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I'm looking for proof of the following commutation relations,

$
[\hat{n}, \hat{a}^k] = -k a^k, \quad \quad \quad \quad [\hat{n}, \hat{a}^{\dagger k}] = -k \hat{a}^{\dagger k}
$

where $\hat{n}$ is the number operator $\hat{n} = \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a}$. Does someone have any idea how to prove them?

$
[\hat{n}, \hat{a}^k] = [\hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a}, \hat{a}^k] = !!!!
$

I know that I can use the relation $[AB,C] = A[B,C] + [A,C]B $, but how to deal with the exponent k on $\hat{a}^k$?

Thanks!!

Comment: That you be good that you recall on which spaces you're working and what are the definition of the symbols you wrote.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The states of the quantum system are here represented in the Fock-basis ${\ket{n}}, n \in \mathcal{N}_0  $

Comment: Try applying the commutators to a basis made of eigenstates of the number operator.

Comment: Can you do it for k=1?